# C# SerialPort - Strange Behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I am trying to use a Serial Port to interface with a camera. Now, the camera has its own proprietary protocol, which is fairly simple and uses 6-byte commands and acknowledges.

Now, I am using C# to write the program which interfaces with the camera, since that allows me to use WPF, and I am comfortable with C# anyway.

My problem arises when I try to set up the camera to retreive an image. The Serial Port object works absolutely fine in doing this, when I step through the program. However, as soon as I run it at full speed, for some reason I end up with the messages at the port being very badly read and even missed. I get to the end of the setup process, just before I begin to retreive the actual data, and there are still commands and things which are still in the port's in buffer.

Now, this solution is, admittedly, just a very hacky attempt to learn the protocol and get the thing working at the moment, and I fully intend to improve it later, but I just cannot figure out why it does this. The camera isn't supposed to sent the next packet until I have acknowledged the last one, so I can only assume that the serial port object is problematic, not the camera or my handling of the protocol.

Could it be because I have (lazily, yes) got this function on the UI thread?

Here's the code:

```
private void retreivePhoto()
    {
        progressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        photo = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"/photos/" + (photoNum++) + ".jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        port.Open();
        progressBar1.Value = 0.5;
        setup.theMessage = setup.JPEG();
        port.Write(setup.theMessage, 0, setup.theMessage.Length);
        while (port.BytesToRead < 0) ;
        port.Read(received.theMessage, 0, received.theMessage.Length);
        setup.theMessage = setup.Package();
        port.Write(setup.theMessage, 0, setup.theMessage.Length);
        while (port.BytesToRead < 0) ;
        port.Read(received.theMessage, 0, received.theMessage.Length);
        setup.theMessage = (byte[])Message.SNAPSHOT.Clone();
        port.Write(setup.theMessage, 0, setup.theMessage.Length);
        while (port.BytesToRead < 0) ;
        port.Read(received.theMessage, 0, received.theMessage.Length);
        setup.theMessage = (byte[])Message.BLANK.Clone();
        setup.theMessage[1] = (byte)Message.MessageTypes.GETPICTURE;
        setup.theMessage[2] = (byte)Message.PictureType.SNAPSHOT;
        port.Write(setup.theMessage, 0, setup.theMessage.Length);
        while (port.BytesToRead < 0) ;
        port.Read(received.theMessage, 0, received.theMessage.Length);
        while (port.BytesToRead < 0) ;
        port.Read(received.theMessage, 0, received.theMessage.Length);
        int length = (received.theMessage[5] << 16) + (received.theMessage[4] << 8) + received.theMessage[3];
        length /= data.theMessage.Length-6;
        byte[] temp = {0xaa, 0x0e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
        port.DiscardInBuffer();
        port.Write(temp, 0, temp.Length);

        int next = 0;
        int bytes;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if ((bytes = port.BytesToRead) > 0)
            {
                port.Read(data.theMessage, 0, data.theMessage.Length);
                if (bytes < data.theMessage.Length)
                {
                    photo.Write(data.theMessage, 4, bytes - 6);
                }
                else
                {
                    photo.Write(data.theMessage, 4, data.theMessage.Length - 6);
                }
                photo.Flush();
            }


            next = ((data.theMessage[1] << 8) + data.theMessage[0]) + 1;

            byte[] nextBytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(next);

            if (length - i == 1)
            {
                temp[4] = temp[5] = 0xf0;
            }
            else
            {
                temp[4] = nextBytes[0];
                temp[5] = nextBytes[1];
            }

            port.Write(temp, 0, temp.Length);
        }

        progressBar1.Value = 1.0;
        photo.Flush();
        photo.Close();
        port.Close();
        progressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    }
```

Here is the camera's datasheet which describes the protocol. http://www.4dsystems.com.au/downloads/micro-CAM/Docs/uCAM-DS-rev7.pdf

Comment: aaarg my eyes - try laying your code out so that it looks a bit more enticing to a potential answeree

Comment: Perhaps better to use events rather than `while (port.BytesToRead < 0)`

Comment: Take a look at the `serliaPort.ErrorReceived` and `serialPort.DataReceived` event

Comment: Sorry, I know the code is messy. As I said, I intend to improve the code later, and that will mean using events.

Comment: At the moment, I am just trying to familiarize myself with SerialPort and the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (port.BytesToRead < 0) ;
port.Read(received.theMessage, 0, received.theMessage.Length);
```

Doesn't mean that you will read `received.theMessage.Length` bytes. it can be anything between 1 & `received.theMessage.Length`. You should check the returned value

Comment: I see now that this is the problem. Is there any particular reason that this is the case? Why would it not just fill my buffer with as much data as it can?

Comment: Your device (& serial comm.) is slower than your computer. You start to read immediately when a byte available. Maybe device hasn't sent the second byte yet.

Comment: I see. Well, I have changed my code to make sure it reads so many bytes at a time. I'll see if this works.